# Is it possible for a Creature permanent to become a non-Creature permanent without losing its abliities?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The [Oath of the Gatewatch release notes](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/oath-gatewatch-release-notes-2016-01-13) say the following in the section about [Stone Haven Outfitter](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Stone%20Haven%20Outfitter):

> In this context, “equipped creatures you control” and “equipped creature you control” refer to any creatures you control with Equipment attached to them. **In the highly unusual case that Stone Haven Outfitter becomes an Equipment, the meaning of its abilities doesn’t change.** The bonuses continue to refer to any equipped creature you control. They aren’t bonuses applied solely to the creature Stone Haven Outfitter is attached to.

I am trying to determine whether the highlighted case is at all possible. I know that I can turn non-Creature, non-Equipment Artifacts into Equipments with [Bludgeon Brawl](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bludgeon%20Brawl), and that I can turn non-Artifact permanents into Artifacts with cards like [Mycosynth Lattice](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mycosynth%20Lattice). So, for that highlighted case to be relevant, the only requirement is for Stone Haven Outfitters to become a non-Creature permanent. Is there any way to do that with currently existing cards?

Alternatively, is there any way for a non-Creature permanent to gain Stone Haven Outfitter's abilities?

Comment: Do you agree with the assertion that Stone Haven Outfitter's abilities still exist, and work, if it becomes an Equipment?

Comment: Well, if it becomes an Equipment in a way that doesn't cause it to lose the abilities, then yes, it would still have them. What I'm trying to determine is whether that's possible in the first place.

Comment: What happens if you mirrorweave in response to a licid activation?

Comment: Copying would push off the interesting abilities.

Comment: @HaoYe Actually, that just may work, if you have the Licid become a copy of the Outfitters in response to activating its ability.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I would think that if the licid ability resolves before the copy, the creature would become unattached due to state-based actions, but if the copy occurs while the licid ability is on the stack, it might work.

Comment: @HaoYe When the Licid resolves, it is no longer a creature, and wouldn't be affected by Mirrorweave.

Comment: @DrunkCynic If the Mirrorweave resolves before the licid ability, the copy effect will already be applied, and it doesn't matter if Mirrorweave would affect the permanent again.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Yes, if Mirrorweave is on top of the activated Licid Ability on the stack, it will work. I was highlighting the event of the activated Licid Ability on top of the Mirrorweave, and why it fails, clarifying the point expressed by HaoYe.

Comment: @DrunkCynic - Ah, you're correct, I missed that Mirrorweave wouldn't affect the object if the licid ability had already resolved.

Comment: I would assume that even though the creature card is no longer a creature, unless the card changing the creature card specifically states "Loses all abilities" Even if it became an equipment the Stone haven Outfitter would still have its abilities... however I'm not sure.

Comment: It seems to me that the terminology of this question is a bit off. Being an equipment would mean having an attribute other than "creature", while "non-creature" would mean not having the "creature" attribute. Having an attribute other than "creature" is not necessarily equivalent to not having the "creature" attribute. i.e. ("not creature" attribute) != (not "creature attribute").

Comment: I specifically asked about the creature becoming a non-creature because a creature cannot be equipped or otherwise attached to another creature. So losing the creature type is a necessary but not sufficient condition for creating the quoted situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is the highly unusual case they talk about:

Have [Bludgeon Brawl](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBludgeon%20Brawl%5d), [Dominating Licid](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDominating%20Licid%5d) (or any other Licid) and [Stone Haven Outfitter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStone%20Haven%20Outfitter%5d) on the battlefield.

So far every permanent is just as they are printed.

Activate the Licid targeting a creature. Respond by casting [Mirrorweave](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMirrorweave%5d) on the Outfitter.

When Mirrorweave is resolved the Licid is an exact copy of a printed Outfitter. So it loses the "You control enchanted creature." ability too here.

When the Licid's activated ability is resolved it becomes an Enchantment - Aura and stops being a creature and it becomes attached to the creature. It still has all abilities of the Outfitter.

Cast [Mycosynth Lattice](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMycosynth%20Lattice%5d).

The Licid becomes an Artifact in addition to it other types. Bludgeon Brawl therefore makes it an Equipment with Equip 2 and "Equipped creature gets +2/+0", based on it having CMC 2 from being a copy of Outfitter. It retains its other abilities.

The Licid is now considered as both equipping as enchanting the creature it's attached to because all that matters for being equipped/enchanted is that it is attached and is an Equipment/Aura.

The enchanted/equipped creature will have +2/+0 because of the Brawl and +1/+1 for each Outfitter you control.

The Licid's typeline and textbox will be:

> Enchantment Artifact - Aura Equipment
>
> Enchant creature
> Equip 2
> Equipped creature gets +2/+0.
> Equipped creatures you control get +1/+1.
> Whenever an equipped creature you control dies, draw a card.

Comment: It seems like this should work, but it would be great to have a complete writeup of how/why it works (i.e. what characteristics are changing when the Mirrorweave resolves and when the licid ability resolves).

Comment: I'm not sure that a detailed description of such a corner case is really worth it. It's not like anyone short of an L3+ judge is expected to really understand those interactions.

Comment: @DrunkCynic Ah, yes, I think you're right. I'll edit it

Comment: @DrunkCynic that won't be necessary. Equip merely means "attach to creature" which it already is. Being equipped only requires the permanent to be attached and having the Equipment subtype, and being enchanted only means being attached and having the Aura subtype

Comment: @LovesTha That's some twisted logic. You think it's not worth explaining an interaction, because players don't need to understand unusual interactions? Players are still responsible for understanding the rules and how the cards work, and an "interaction" is just a combination of those. Plus, the point of this site (especially the MTG questions) is exactly to explain stuff like this.

Comment: @murgatroid99 People commonly over emphasize the usefulness of understanding the extreme corner cases. I'll hold that this question isn't the place to fully explain the intricacies. The person asking just wants to know the combination of cards to get there.

Comment: You're arguing with "the person asking". Presuming to tell me what I wanted out of my own question is not helping your case. Besides that, I hope you understand that the 10 upvotes on my last comment represent an unusual expression of community agreement, so claiming that the consensus is against me here won't work either.

Comment: @IvoBeckers Do you mind if I edit this answer to expand the sequence of events and add descriptions of what changes when each thing resolves?

Comment: Actually, I just realized that for this to work, the Mycosynth Lattice has to enter the battlefield after the Licid ability resolves. Otherwise, the Licid ability's "becomes an Enchantment" effect would override Mycosynth Lattice's "is an Artifact" effects. (they're in the same layer, so timestamps apply, and "becomes [type]" removes all existing types)

Comment: @murgatroid99 I think you're right. I'll edit the answer in a couple of minutes. I'll also expand the anwer a bit. Feel free to expand it even further when I'm done

Comment: @murgatroid99 Disagree; licid as a creature, w/ Mycosynth in play, is an Artifact Creature, even after the copy effect of Mirrorweave. From the resolution of the licid ability, licid becomes an Enchantment - Aura, stops being an artifact creature, and is attached to target creature. Afterwards, the static ability makes at in Artifact Enchantment - Aura as a state based action. As a non-creature, non-equipment artifact, the static ability of Bludgeon Brawler is applied, making it an Artifact Equipment Enchantment - Aura.

Comment: "Afterwards, the static ability makes at in Artifact Enchantment - Aura as a state based action." This part is entirely incorrect. What we have here are two continuous effects: "Permanents are artifacts in addition to their other types" and "Dominating Licid becomes an Enchantment - Aura". These are not applied as state based actions but are computed continuously. Since they are in the same layer (613.1d) they are applied in timestamp order (613.6). The Licid effect is newer, so it overrides the Mycosynth Lattice's effect.

Comment: @doppelgreener I rolled back your edit, because I think it was wrong. Mirrorweave makes the lycid into a copy of the Outfitter including its mana cost which has converted mana cost 2.

Comment: @IvoBeckers Oh!! You're right, that's where you were getting the 2 from. Thanks. @_@

Comment: Can you still pay U to end the enchanting effect, and if so what happens?